# JS Rock paper scissors game, animation issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to coding. I followed a tutorial by dev Ed.

When I click on the button 'Lets Play' It should fade out and show the game. It worked at first but at some point it stopped.

There may be more errors  than this but I am not able to test it until I can get past this first one. I apologise if it is something simple and I am very new to this. Is anyone able to help me out with this?

```js
const game = () => {
  let pScore = 0; //Player score
  let cScore = 0; //Computer score
}
//Start the game
const startGame = () => {
  const playBtn = document.querySelector('.intro button'); // Lets play button
  const introScreen = document.querySelector('.intro'); //This is the main screen of the game that will fade when the button is pressed. 
  const match = document.querySelector('.match');

  playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    introScreen.classList.add('fadeOut');
    match.classList.add('fadeIn');
  });
};

//play match
const playMatch = () => {
  const options = document.querySelectorAll('.options button'); //Selects all the options from the buttons
  const playerHand = document.querySelector('.player-hand');
  const computerHand = document.querySelector('.computer-hand');
  const hands = document.querySelectorAll('.hands img');

  hands.forEach(hand => {
    hand.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
      this.style.animation = '';
    });
  })
  //Computer Options
  const computerOptions = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

  options.forEach(option => {
    option.addEventListener('click', function() {
      //computer choice
      const computerNumber = math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
      const computerChoice = computerOptions[computerNumber];
      //Here is the where we call compare hands everytime the user preses one of the buttons
      setTimeout(() => {
        compareHands(this.textContent, computerChoice);
        //Update Images
        playerHand.src = `./assets/${this.textContent}.png`;
        computerHand.src = `./assets/${computerChoice}.png`;
      }, 2000);
      //Animation
      playerHand.style.animation = "shakePlayer 2s ease";
      computerHand.style.animation = "shakeComputer 2s ease";
    });
  });
};

const updateScore = () => {
  const playerScore = document.querySelector('.player-score p');
  const computerScore = document.querySelector('.computer-score p');
  playerScore.textContent = pScore;
  computerScore.textContent = cScore;
}

//The function below is getting the computers choice from above 
const compareHands = (playerChoice, computerChoice) => {
  //Update Text
  const winner = document.querySelector('.winner');
  //Checking for a tie
  if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
    winner.textContent = 'It is a tie';
    return; //If it is a tie, this will stop the rest of the code from running. and will end the function.
  }
}
//Check for Rock
if (playerChoice === 'rock') {
  if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
    winner.textContent = 'Player Wins';
    pScore++;
    updateScore();
    return;
  } else {
    winner.textContent = 'Computer Wins';
    cScore++;
    updateScore();
    return;
  }
}
//Check for paper
if (playerChoice === 'paper') {
  if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
    winner.textContent = 'Computer Wins';
    cScore++;
    updateScore();
    return;

  } else {
    winner.textContent = 'Player Wins';
    pScore++;
    updateScore();
  }
}
//Check for Scissors
if (playerChoice === 'scissors') {
  if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
    winner.textContent = 'Computer Wins';
    cScore++;
    return;
  } else {
    winner.textContent = 'Player Wins';
    pScore++;
    updateScore();
    return;
  }
  //Is call all the the inner  functions.
  startGame();
  playMatch();
};

//start the game function
game();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(39, 41, 68);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.score {
  color: rgb(216, 214, 214);
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.score h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.score p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.intro {
  color: rgb(216, 214, 214);
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.intro h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.intro button,
.match button
/*This is styling the buttons */

{
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: rgb(216, 214, 214);
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgb(45, 117, 96);
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.match {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5;
}

.winner {
  color: rgb(216, 214, 214);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.hands,
.options
/* This is styling the hands section*/

{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.player-hand {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

div.fadeOut
/* This will make the fade out */

{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

@keyframes shakePlayer {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  15% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  35% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  65% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes shakeComputer {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  15% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  35% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  65% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  85% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="game">
  <!-- This is the score section-->
  <div class="score">
    <div class="player-score">
      <!-- This will show the player score-->
      <h2>Player</h2>
      <p>0</p>
    </div>
    <div class="computer-score">
      <!--This will show the computers score-->
      <h2>Computer</h2>
      <p>0</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="intro">
    <!-- this is the main part of the gamne-->
    <h1>Rock Paper and Scissors</h1>
    <button>Let's play</button>
  </div>

  <div class="match fadeOut">
    <h2 class="winner">Choose an option</h2>
    <div class="hands">
      <img class="player-hand" src="./assets/rock.png" alt="rock">
      <!-- This is the players hand that is on the left hand side. -->
      <img class="computer-hand" src="./assets/rock.png" alt="rock">
      <!--This is the computers hand -->
    </div>
    <!-- This will show the hands-->

    <div class="options">
      <!--This will be where the player can select their options-->
      <button class="rock">rock</button>
      <button class="paper">paper</button>
      <button class="scissors">scissors</button>
    </div>
    <!--This will be where the player can select their options-->
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Start by fixing the console error. It is very specific - you cannot have `return` outside a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a mistake in `compareHands` with closing the curly brackets too early. The `startGame()` and `playMatch()` are being called in that last `if` statement if you follow the brackets, so the event listener in `startGame()` is not being added to the button.

Fix the brackets issue in `compareHands` (look at line 66 and see the brackets are closing before it gets to the `if` statements) and move `startGame()` and `playMatch()` outside of that function, like `game()`, so that they are called and the event listener is added to the button.

https://jsfiddle.net/53Lsbyxu/20/

Comment: Thank you this has seemed to fix the issue I was having. More have now come up though. When I press rock paper or scissors nothing happens. i am going to take a look and see if I can figure it out. It is saying pScore is not defined.

Comment: @Ryjonzy glad that's working for you. The pScore error is to do with scope - pScore is not accessible in startGame or playMatch at the moment. A quick fix could be to declare those variables outside of the functions so that they have global scope and are available to all, like https://jsfiddle.net/209dj6b5/3/. Scope resource: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Thank you! I am very new to this and I am finding it extremley difficult to wrap my head around everything haha.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//put scores in a object for ease of use
let scores = {
  player: 0,
  computer: 0
};
let enemies = {
  rock: "scissors",
  paper: "rock",
  scissors: "paper"
};

// you shouldn't define elements in functions
//that means everytime that function is called it's defined again and again, which is unnecessary
// define them at the start
const playBtn = document.querySelector(".intro button");
const introScreen = document.querySelector(".intro");
const match = document.querySelector(".match");
const winner = document.querySelector(".winner");
const options = document.querySelectorAll(".options");
const playerHand = document.querySelector(".player-hand");
const computerHand = document.querySelector(".computer-hand");
const hands = document.querySelectorAll(".hands img");
const playerScore = document.querySelector(".player-score p");
const computerScore = document.querySelector(".computer-score p");

const startGame = () => {
  playBtn.onclick = () => {
    introScreen.classList.add("fadeOut");
    match.classList.add("fadeIn");
  };
};


const playMatch = () => {
//shortend event function
  hands.forEach((hand) => (hand.onanimationend = (e) => (e.target.style.animation = "")));
  options.forEach((option) => {
    option.onclick = (e) => {
    // Object.keys(enemies)=['rock','paper','scissors']
    //using that means you don't have to define another variable saying the same
      const computerChoice = Object.keys(enemies)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
      setTimeout(() => {
        compareHands(e.target.textContent, computerChoice);
        playerHand.src = `./assets/${e.target.textContent}.png`;
        computerHand.src = `./assets/${computerChoice}.png`;
      }, 2000);
      playerHand.style.animation = "shakePlayer 2s ease";
      computerHand.style.animation = "shakeComputer 2s ease";
    };
  });
};

const updateMatch = () => {
  playerScore.textContent = scores.player;
  computerScore.textContent = scores.computer;
};

const compareHands = (playerChoice, computerChoice) => {
//Removed unnecessary if statements.
//instead enemies are determined by the `enemies` object
  if (playerChoice === computerChoice) return (winner.textContent = "It is a tie");

  if (enemies[playerChoice] === computerChoice) {
    scores.computer++;
    winner.textContent = "Computer Wins";
  } else {
    scores.player++;
    winner.textContent = "Player Wins";
  }
  updateMatch();
};
startGame();
playMatch();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(39, 41, 68);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.score {
  color: rgb(216, 214, 214);
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.score h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.score p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.intro {
  color: rgb(216, 214, 214);
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.intro h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.intro button,
.match button
/*This is styling the buttons */

{
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: rgb(216, 214, 214);
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgb(45, 117, 96);
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.match {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5;
}

.winner {
  color: rgb(216, 214, 214);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.hands,
.options
/* This is styling the hands section*/

{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.player-hand {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

div.fadeOut
/* This will make the fade out */

{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

@keyframes shakePlayer {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  15% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  35% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  65% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes shakeComputer {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  15% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  35% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  65% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  85% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  <title>Rock Paper and Scissors</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="game">
    <!-- This is the score section-->
    <div class="score">
      <div class="player-score">
        <!-- This will show the player score-->
        <h2>Player</h2>
        <p>0</p>
      </div>
      <div class="computer-score">
        <!--This will show the computers score-->
        <h2>Computer</h2>
        <p>0</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="intro">
      <!-- this is the main part of the gamne-->
      <h1>Rock Paper and Scissors</h1>
      <button>Let's play</button>
    </div>

    <div class="match fadeOut">
      <h2 class="winner">Choose an option</h2>
      <div class="hands">
        <img class="player-hand" src="./assets/rock.png" alt="rock">
        <!-- This is the players hand that is on the left hand side. -->
        <img class="computer-hand" src="./assets/rock.png" alt="rock">
        <!--This is the computers hand -->
      </div>
      <!-- This will show the hands-->

      <div class="options">
        <!--This will be where the player can select their options-->
        <button class="rock">rock</button>
        <button class="paper">paper</button>
        <button class="scissors">scissors</button>
      </div>
      <!--This will be where the player can select their options-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So what did you change? How does it solve the problem? Code-only answers, especially with this length, don't help much. Please edit your post and add explanation.

Comment: That was not me (op) who commented. Thank you for doing that :)

Comment: @Ryjonzy added comments